# Draw route between two markers

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm learning how to develop web applications using Ext.js, and I'm using Google Maps API to show a map in my page.

I added two markers for two different locations and I would like to draw a polyline between these two markers, how can I do that?

My code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyCV2QUPhqKB67SnuoQLO573e5N2yIaQiwQ"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/ux/GMapPanel.js"></script>

</head>

<body></body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Ext.onReady(function() {
        var w = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {

            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            layout: 'fit',
            header: false,
            border: false,
            style: 'padding: 0; border-width: 0;',
            closable: false,
            draggable: false,
            height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
            width: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'gmappanel',
                region: 'center',
                cls: 'reset-box-sizing',
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.50733,-0.1977981),
                markers: [{
                    lat: 51.50733,
                    lng: -0.1977981,
                    marker:  {title: 'Location 1'},
                    listeners: {
                        click: function(e){
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Its fine', 'and its art.');
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    lat: 53.4083509,
                    lng: -3.0616123,
                    marker: {title: 'Location 2'}
                }],
                mapOptions: {
                    zoom: 16,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
            }]
        });

        w.show();

    });
</script>

</html>
```

I have been searching for some codes and I found this one that draws a polyline, but it says that "InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map "

```
var flightPathCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
];

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPathCoordinates,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(w);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you did so far (tried)?

Comment: I updated the answer, I'm really newbie yet, I started learning about ext.js components yesterday, so I've been searching some codes to adapt but nothing seems to work.

Comment: It means that variable `w` (window) is not yet created. Where is your second code fragment resides?

Comment: I added the second code bellow "w.show()", but the variable is being declared when I create the window, right here: "var w = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {"

Comment: It's better to place this code in `afterrender` or `afterlayout` listeners of `gmappanel` item. Just put `listeners` property after `xtype`.

Comment: I inserted the code inside a listeners just like you said and the error disappeared thank you, the only issue I have now is that I still can see the polyline.

Comment: There should be some method in `flightPath` to draw or to show polyline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polyline's setMap method has one argument that is required - an instance of a google map. ([Google Maps JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Polyline))

Your polyline code is fine, but when you call setMap you pass the variable `w`, which I assume is your ExtJS window, when you need to be passing it the actual google map instance. That can be accessed by using the `gmap` property of the `gmappanel` class. To get to the `gmappanel` class from your window, you can use the `down` method ([ExtJS API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.Queryable-method-down)) by doing `gmappanel = w.down('gmappanel')`or you can just get it because you know it's the only item that the window contains by doing `gmappanel = w.items.first()`;

Then you can just do `gmap = gmappanel.gmap` to get the actual google map instance.

So in your second code block, just replace the last line with this:

```
flightPath.setMap(w.down('gmappanel').gmap);
```